# When transitioning IU Router states with Google maps on uiGmapIsReady picks up previous map not the new one

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-promise, angular-google-maps

I am using UI Router and UI Google Maps.

According to the documentation I should use `uiGmapIsReady` to know whether the maps are ready to use on the page.  This works great in isolation.  But when transitioning from one page to another where maps exist on both pages problems occur.

The main problem seems to be that `uiGmapIsReady` gets fired instantly with the data of the OLD map not the new one.  I can prove this by changing one map to "satellite" and then switching to the new page.  The new page is road map by default but the map exposed by `uiGmapIsReady` has a type of satellite!

I've tried a number of things but nothing seems to work.  Ive tried subscribing to `uiGmapIsReady` only one the `$viewContentLoaded` or `$stateChangeSuccess` events have been fired but unfortunately they fire too soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the source code I figured out how to resolve this

```
this.uiGmapIsReady
    .promise(this.uiGmapIsReady.instances() + 1)
    .then((mapInstances: any[]) => {
        var map: google.maps.Map = mapInstances[mapInstances.length - 1].map;
    });
```

The number you pass into the promise is the number of map instances you expect there to be.  If the number is wrong then the promise won't return. So you have to use `instances()` which tells you the current count and add 1 to it (which is the number of maps your new page will create).

Lastly you just need to take the last map in the array, as that will always be the newest one.